# Saving data to an existing plist

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios6, plist

I am working on a project that has a simple tableview with detail view.

**Data source is a plist**. I am trying to allow user input to be saved into the plist and shown in tableview. i have created a add view controller which gets presented and dismissed modally and has two text fields which allow the user to add the name of the city and name of the states, also a text field to input description.

Problem: how to save this data to my existing plist and show it in the `tableview`. Here is my code for the table view:

```
@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize content, searchResults;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
}

- (IBAction)add;
{
AddViewController* controller = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [self.searchResults count];

} else {
    return [self.content count];

}
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF['city'] BEGINSWITH[c] %@ ", searchText];

searchResults = [[content filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] retain];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"]];

}

return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDetails" sender: self];
}
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *DVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {

        DVC.cityImageString = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"];
        DVC.cityTextString = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityText"];
        DVC.cityNameString = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        DVC.stateNameString = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
    } else {

        DVC.cityImageString = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityImage"];
        DVC.cityTextString = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"cityText"];
        DVC.cityNameString = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];
        DVC.stateNameString = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"state"];
    }

}
}
```

**and here is the code for `addViewController.h`:**

```
@interface AddViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{

IBOutlet UITextField *cityTextField;
IBOutlet UITextField *stateTextField;
IBOutlet UITextView *cityDescription;

UIImagePickerController* imagePicker;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar* navigationBar;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *cityTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *stateTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *cityDescription;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* choosePhotoButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* takePhotoButton;



- (IBAction)save;
- (IBAction)cancel;

- (IBAction)choosePhoto;
- (IBAction)takePhoto;

@end
```

and at last the add view controller .m

```
@implementation AddViewController
@synthesize cityTextField, stateTextField, cityDescription;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)save
{
// Make sure the user has entered at least a recipe name
if (self.cityTextField.text.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Whoops..."
                              message:@"Please enter a city name"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    return;
}

if (self.stateTextField.text.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Whoops..."
                              message:@"Please enter a city name"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    return;
}
// Make sure the user has entered at least a recipe name
if (self.cityDescription.text.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Whoops..."
                              message:@"Please enter city description"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    return;
}

self.name = self.cityTextField.text;
self.name = self.stateTextField.text;
self.description = self.cityDescription.text;


if ([[self parentViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:)]){

    [[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (IBAction)cancel {
{

    if ([[self parentViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)]){

        [[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {

        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
}

- (IBAction)choosePhoto
{
// Show the image picker with the photo library
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([cityDescription isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != cityDescription) {

    [cityDescription resignFirstResponder];
}
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[cityTextField resignFirstResponder];
[stateTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
// We get here when the user has successfully picked an image.
// Put the image in our property and set it on the button.

if (imagePicker) {
    self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self.choosePhotoButton setImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {

    if (picker) {
        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [self.takePhotoButton setImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[imagePicker release];
imagePicker = nil;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[imagePicker release];
imagePicker = nil;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

i know there are tons of almost similar questions and believe me i have looked at so many of them and i think i am hitting the wall with this one and i cant think of a proper way to do this. it may be so simple but for the life of me i cant figure this out and thats why i am trying to ask for help. i truly appreciate any help i can get. if needs be i can place the sample project on git hub for ease of access. also the project is built in ios 6 and the latest Xcode.

P.S. here is the link to the project on git hub: https://github.com/AdrianPhillips/TableSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as every one has pointed out you can not write to the plist that is in your main bundle. You need to copy it from the bundle to your application document directory. Then you can just init from and write to the path in your documents directory. The other issue you have, is that nothing is communicating the new data from the AddViewController back to the TableViewController. You should create a protocol and delegate for your AddViewController.

For all the gore details see my pull request on GitHub.
https://github.com/GayleDDS/TableSearch.git

Comment: @ Gayle, thanks for the contribution. delegate is a nice approach and it saves the data but not all of it. the image does not get saved. that is one of the important part of my question. bob cromwell had an approach with saving the plist copy and it also works but it does not save the image chosen from library and taken from camera. can you help out with the image save part, that will answer the question completely. many thanks

Comment: @CodeMonkey I added the image saving and reading. Got tired and lazy last night. Cheers. see https://github.com/GayleDDS/TableSearch.git

Comment: saw the addition. brilliant. but one issue. the segue to detail view does not show the image added in the detail view. any idea why?

Comment: @CodeMonkey. Dh'o I never looked at the detail view. The issue is the detail view only looks for images in the bundle and not the documents directory. But the real problem is a lack of encapsulation of the model logic. I made the larger change to fix the true problem and not just the symptom. I moved the model logic out of the view controllers and into a category on NSDictionary. Add the file path code into the application delegate.

Comment: nicely done gayle. you practically changed that sample app that i had. since you gave me the most complete answer i am awarding the bounty to you. i have managed to complete the other crud version as well. it took me a while but i did it. one thing though in my version i have placed remove row and am removing the row and deleting it from copy of the plist. how do i implement the remove row in delegate version? i know you don't have to answer this last question but i would appreciate it.

Comment: Adding swipe to delete is easy just implement tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: see my GitHub project for details. I also added support for edit mode in the table.

Comment: @CodeMonkey A good exercise for you would be to reorder support to the table view. You need to enable "Shows Re-order Controls" for the table cell prototype in the storyboard. Then implement 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
in the TableViewController.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about the good exercise. I need as much as I can get.once again thanks for your help and I'll see you around stack overflow. And by the way I was able to finish the entire project with the crud method I had and have implemented the remove row in there as well I just didn't know how to apply that using the dictionary. But thanks anyway. Your answer was a great time saver.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Your welcome. FYI the Stanford iOS programing class on iTunesU is awesome. https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your code that do the actual "save" work. I guess it should be in the `UIAlertView` delegate,right ? And you did not tell us what's your problem. Following code maybe what's you seeking.

[content writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]

Another reminder is: you should NOT save the plist back to main bundle, save it to Documents or Cache or other folder.

Comment: That is the question bob, I don't have a save method. I can't figure out how to save the strings to the plist that I have and show them in the existing tableview. I have placed the project on github and the link is in the comments of the other answer. Will you be a prince and take a look at the project and help me implement the methods I am looking for please.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I send a pull request to your repo. By the way, I think you should figure out how to do this by yourself.

Comment: @ Bob thanks for the code now i understand it better. one question though how do i reload the table view in order to show the newly entered data?

Comment: `[tableView reloadData]` I think you should refactor your code a bit.

Comment: i tried using reload data in viewdidload but cant get it to work. how do you mean by refracting my code?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will be invoked only when you access `self.view` and the view is `nil`. For test purpose, You can do following in `viewWillAppear`.You could You need to re-read the plist to `content` in `TableViewController` (note from the Documents folder NOT the main bundle one) and do `[ view reloadData]`. You may find that it'hard to notify your UI to update it. You should move your Model (M of MVC) code to a sperate class. And set up some update mechanism yourself,e.g. KVO or delegate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29775/discussion-between-bob-cromwell-and-code-monkey)

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the plist to the Documents folder first. You can't edit it into the original app folder. You can use this class to do this:

```
- (void) CreatePlistCopyInDocuments:(NSString *)plistName {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath];

    if (success) {
        return;
    }

    // The writable file does not exist, so copy from the bundle to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writablePath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

You have just to pass the plist name to it.
Then you have to load it into some NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
NSString *documents = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"];
            NSString *plistInDocuments = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserData.plist"];
            NSMutableDictionary *plistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistInDocuments];
```

After you have updated the values for the dictionary, you have to write the file back to the documents like this:

```
[plistData writeToFile:plistInDocuments atomically:YES];
```